# When using webkitRelativePath is the path separator operating system specific?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a directory upload feature with limited browser support (namely Chrome or Chromium based browsers). To that end I'm using an `HTMLInput` element with the `webkitdirectory` attribute. What I need to know is will the directory separators in the `webkitRelativePath` property of the selected `File` objects use operating system specific directory separators. It looks like according to [this W3C draft](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/#relative-path) it is specified to always be unix style separators, but it would be good to have confirmation of this (if possible for FireFox as well). Unfortunately the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath) doesn't specify.

Here is a snippet that demonstrates the functionality:

```js
var dirInput = document.getElementById('dirInputTest');
var output = document.getElementById('dirListing');
dirInput.addEventListener(
  'change',
  function () {
    var files = Array.from(dirInput.files);
    output.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      output.innerHTML += files[i].webkitRelativePath + '\n';
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<body>
<input id="dirInputTest" type="file" webkitdirectory />
<pre id="dirListing">
</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Well... that's what the current specs text ask for, so if you are only interested in implementations that do follow these specs, you can be sure that "A relative path is a string consisting of one or more path segments joined by '/' (U+002F SOLIDUS) that does not start with '/' (U+002F SOLIDUS).", and if you find an implementation that doesn't follow that rule, then it's a buggy implementation. Also, just for curiosity, what are you willing to do with these pathes?

Comment: This is for an upload feature that preserves the directory structure of the uploaded folder. So I have to turn the flat list of files into a tree structure to create the respective containers before uploading the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I got around to spinning up a Windows VM and I can confirm that all of the major browsers (Chrome, Fire-Fox, Edge) use the forward slash path separator regardless of operating system (I did not test Opera or Internet Explorer).